# Python For loop to change long dictionary keys of same structure to string integers

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a bunch of csv files in a folder that I have saved into a dictionary so that each entry is its own dataframe. Each dataframe is a few columns of time series data.

```
for df in csv_files:
  
  df_name = df
  filename = "{}".format(df)
  #print(filename)
  dfs[df_name] = pd.read_csv(filename, sep = ',', skiprows= 13)
  dfs[df_name].loc[0] = 0 # set first line to zeros
```

All of the dictionary keys right now are the name of the data file so if I want to look at just one dataframe I have to type in the whole path.

```
dfs['/content/drive/My Drive/LAICPMS 72123/ANP/ANP 072123_7.csv']
```

But this isn't very convenient. I'm able to change each key manually as follows

```
dfs['7'] = dfs.pop('/content/drive/My Drive/LAICPMS 72123/ANP/ANP 072123_7.csv')
```

but I'd really like to use a loop to rename each key as a string integer.

I tried to make a list of string integers by counting the number of files in the folder

```
#how many files are in folder
count = 0
for path in listdir("/content/drive/My Drive/LAICPMS 72123/ANP"):
  if isfile(join("/content/drive/My Drive/LAICPMS 72123/"ANP, path)):
    count+=1
#print(count)

#make a list of integer as long as number of files
num_files = list(range(count))


#convert integers to strings
list_st = map(str, num_files)
#print(list(list_st))

for x in list_st:
  print(x)
```

which successfully counts them and makes a new list, but then I'm lost on how to set up a loop to rename the dictionary keys with this list. Clearly, I'm not understanding something about indexing lists and dictionaries.

Comment: "but then I'm lost on how to set up a loop to rename the dictionary keys with this list." - what should happen each time through the loop? (Perhaps, storing a key/value pair into a new dict?) What value do you want to process each time through the loop? (Perhaps, a dict key?) What is the **rule that tells you** how the integers you want to use as keys correspond to the filenames? If you want to process the filename to get a number out of it, fine; first write that logic and make a function for it. If you just want to use ascending numbers as keys - why not just use a list?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the dictionary, then you already have the number, no need to count.

You could create another dictionary like so:

```
dfs_new = dict(enumerate(dfs.values()))
```

But in the above case, you **probably just want a `list`**, in which case, all you need is:

```
dfs_new = list(df.values())
```

Not sure why you want the keys to be strings, but if they must, you could do:

```
dfs_new = {str(i):v for i,v in enumerate(dfs.values())}
```

In general, if you have some set of `new_keys` that correspond (in order) to the keys that must be replaced, you can do:

```
dict_new = dict(zip(new_keys, some_dict.values())
```

You can always re-assign to the same variable if you don't need the original dict anymore. This is practically always the best approach. If you *must* modify the dictionary in-place (you probably shouldn't *have* to in a well-designed program, but it happens...), you could do the following, assuming `data` is the dictionary:

```
for (original_key, value), new_key in zip(list(data.items()), new_keys):
    data[new_key] = value
    del data[original_key]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through dictionary keys and number then at the same time using `enumerate`. However, you are going to change the dictionary inside the loop, so fix the keys list before starting to loop `list(dfs.keys())`, otherwise something strange can happen.

You may also want to save the mapping from index to path for debugging. I created `index_2_path` dictionary to do so:

```
dfs = {"path1": "df1", "path2": "df2", "path3": "df3"}
index_2_path = {}

for i, path in enumerate(list(dfs.keys())):
    dfs[str(i)] = dfs.pop(path)
    index_2_path[str(i)] = path

print("dfs:", dfs)
print("index_2_path:", index_2_path)
```

Output:

```
dfs: {'0': 'df1', '1': 'df2', '2': 'df3'}
index_2_path: {'0': 'path1', '1': 'path2', '2': 'path3'}
```

You can also use any predefined or generated list for renaming, not only numbers:

```
dfs = {"path1": "df1", "path2": "df2", "path3": "df3"}
new_keys = ["a", "b", "c"]
index_2_path = {}

for new_name, path in zip(new_keys, list(dfs.keys())):
    dfs[new_name] = dfs.pop(path)
    index_2_path[new_name] = path

print("dfs:", dfs)
print("index_2_path:", index_2_path)
```

Output:

```
dfs: {'a': 'df1', 'b': 'df2', 'c': 'df3'}
index_2_path: {'a': 'path1', 'b': 'path2', 'c': 'path3'}
```